# Pegar Id do usuário logado

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Como faço para pegar o Id do usuário logado no site, para depois inserir em uma outra tabela?

Tentando explicar melhor. Eu tenho uma action chamada CriarPub, que permite que o usuário escreva suas publicações no site. Na minha tabela publicações, tem o id do usuario, que é obrigatório, para eu saber quem publicou no site. A minha ideia, é na hora que o usuário clicar em criar publicações, esse campo da tabela publicações, receba o Id do usuário logado, permitindo assim, o insert.

Comment: Acredito que isso possa ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25453584/2263584 Embora .NET já esteja na versão 4.5, acho que isso ainda deve funcionar.

Comment: @TiagoSilva Estou utilizando o Membership.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como nessa resposta no SOen: **[get-the-id-of-the-current-user-asp-net-membership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159087/get-the-id-of-the-current-user-asp-net-membership/13159197#13159197)**

Para um usuário aleatório que você precise, faça assim:

```
MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser("username");
string userId = mu.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
```

Para um usuário logado, você pode fazer assim:

```
string userId = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();
```

Comment: Devo implementar isso no método membershipuser getuser() correto?

Comment: Entendi. Só mais uma dúvida,  um dos parâmetros desse método é o bool user online, ou algo assim. O que eu faço com ele?  É necessário a implementação dele?

Comment: Olá. Desculpe a demora para responder. Confere se é isso mesmo, por favor.   public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline){
  string userId = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();  } Qual seria o retorno desse metodo?

Comment: Confere se ficou mais claro agora.